# GetElementByID from HTML <form> without id

Tags: powershell, automation

I need help to automatically login to my website (localhost) with username and pass. 
I've tried different solutions, and it works when I don't have `<form />` tag.
So, as you can see below, my username and pass fields are in the form which doesn't have `id` tag.

Do I must to have an id, or is there another way to extract data?

**My short html with `form` tag:**

```
<div class="container panel-body form-horizontal">
 <form action="/Account/Login" method="post">
<input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" 
 value="0D05ZaUJrnKwnwgQ2CbQEmLt2-4gaOPEsJtMPxKcBBCFWzcd9FLtOEEHhCpAcSL3Z9otKmlxJ4CEkdkVVGEnSoD-O6W7Fo0ZUy1jp36bbz01" />        <div class="row">
         <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-5" for="Username">Username</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input autofocus="" class="form-control" data-val="true" 
data-val-required="Field is required." id="UserName" name="UserName" placeholder="Username" type="text" value="" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label col-md-5 col-sm-5" 
 for="Password">Password</label>
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7">
                    <input autofocus="" class="form-control" data-val="true" 
  data-val-required="Field is required." id="Password" name="Password" 
  placeholder="Password" type="password" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-offset-5">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" value="Login">
                    <div class="panel-body logon-error">
                        <span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="LogOnError" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-5 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-2">
            <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-md-offset-5 col-sm-offset-5">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form></div>
</div>
```

**My powershell script looks for now like this:**

```
$ie = New-Object -ComObject 'internetExplorer.Application'
$ie.Visible= $true # Make it visible

$username="admin"

$password="admin"

$ie.Navigate("http://localhost:4991/Home/LogIn")

 While ($ie.Busy -eq $true) {Start-Sleep -Seconds 3;}

#here I dont know how to call my DOM elements in a form container.

 $ie.Document.getElementById("").
 contentWindow.document.getElementByID("UserName").value = "admin"

 $usernamefield = $ie.document.getElementByID('UserName')
 $usernamefield.value = "$username"

 $passwordfield = $ie.document.getElementByID('Password')
 $passwordfield.value = "$password"

 $Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}
 $Link.click()

 $ie.Quit()
```

Comment: `$form = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0]`?

Comment: It works fine for me after replacing `$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("button") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}` with `$Link = $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName("input") | Where-Object {$_.type -eq 'submit'}`

Comment: I found Invoke-webrequest function, but after I run it, nothing really happens. I can't see the result in ie?